# Pipeline Shell Script Permission Issue on .NET Build Attempt

Tags: bash, debian, pipeline

I am trying to build an ASP.NET5 application via Bluemix Pipeline using a shell script to configure a runtime that supports .NET builds with DNVM. When building the application we need to get dependencies from Mono 4.0 (such as kestrel) but the latest Mono available via `apt-get` is 3.2. I tried to resolve this by adding the Mono deb repository in `/etc/apt/sources.list` so that an `apt-get update` would fetch the latest Mono package but due to a permission error we are not allowed to alter `sources.list` nor add or alter any files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`.

For example, running:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
sudo echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo -i tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
```

Will result in:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Not using `sudo` will give a permission issue and I think we have exhausted all possible workarounds such as `ssh -t -t` and forth.

Does anyone have any suggestions on a workaround for this or an alternative method to run a shell script where a .NET build with DNVM and all dependencies would be supported? Using another language or `cf push` in this case is not an option, we really want to push .NET through pipeline at any cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When experimenting with the pipeline I wasn't able to get it working with Mono either, but if you can get away with just the CoreCLR on Linux then you should be able to. Kestrel, for example, doesn't require Mono anymore.

This was a build script from the beta7 timeframe but it should be close to what's needed to use RC1 now:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install libunwind8 gettext libssl-dev libcurl3-dev zlib1g

curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.sh | DNX_BRANCH=dev sh && source ~/.dnx/dnvm/dnvm.sh
dnvm install 1.0.0-beta7 -r coreclr -a x64

cd src/dotnetstarter
dnu restore
dnu build

cd ../../test/dotnetstarter.tests
dnu restore
dnu build
dnx test

cd ../../src/dotnetstarter
dnu publish --runtime ~/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-coreclr-linux-x64.1.0.0-beta7
```

The app was https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/asp.net5-helloworld and I added the dotnetstarter.tests project which I was trying to run in the pipeline (the dnx test step). The last publish step isn't required but is included to show it was working.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I adopted your code and when trying to run `dnu build` I get the following [stack](http://pastebin.com/3BL3cCsz). Any ideas on this? We can restore and publish it properly but I guess that is of no value unless we can execute a build? I'm using the Hello-World app as well.

Comment: Make sure the "1.0.0-beta7" references are changed to match the dnx version in your app's project.json file. It looks like the app is written to a newer version.

Comment: Of course, should of caught that (sorry, we are students experimenting with IBM products). I don't think I understand this correctly, I get another error now. This is my [project.json](http://pastebin.com/7iKM3VVq), this is the console error: `/home/pipeline/d9e87551-36e6-406b-b164-2d27b7901b2d/src/dotnetstarter/Startup.cs(12,47): DNXCore,Version=v5.0 error CS0103: The name 'WebApplication' does not exist in the current context` and this is line 12: `public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run(args);` Can you see the mistake? Thanks again!

Comment: 1.0.0-beta7 is old and the error implies your app code was written to a newer version like 1.0.0-rc1. What I meant was the build script and the project.json need to be at that version or newer, probably 1.0.0-rc-update1 at this point.

Comment: Thanks, we completely misunderstood you earlier. We changed the version to rc1-final and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to opiethehokie, this is the working script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo --- UPDATING DEPENDENCIES! ---

sudo apt-get update

echo --- DOWNLOADING PACKAGES! ---

sudo apt-get -y install libunwind8 gettext libssl-dev libcurl3-dev zlib1g libcurl4-openssl-dev libicu-dev uuid-dev

echo --- DOWNLOADING DNVM! ---

curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.sh | DNX_BRANCH=dev sh && source ~/.dnx/dnvm/dnvm.sh

echo --- INSTALLING DNVM! ---

dnvm install 1.0.0-rc1-final -r coreclr -a x64

echo --- EXECUTING RESTORE! ---

cd /path-to-project-folder
dnu restore

echo --- EXECUTING BUILD! ---

dnu build

echo --- PUBLISH BUILD (OPTIONAL)! ---

dnu publish --runtime ~/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-coreclr-linux-x64.1.0.0-*`
```